# Sending universal links with brevo (Sendinblue) email leaves a 404

Tags: deep-linking, ios-universal-links, sendinblue

Im sending my universal links through brevo (Sendinblue). It redirects and sends email fine, but leaves a 404 page in safari with the error:

`build-verify URL: build UrlParms: build-verify URL: cleanURL: invalid URL: host missing`